# LessCss duplicated domain when interpolating?

Tags: javascript, css, less, dotless

Before loading less, Site.base is set to `http://localhost/images`

On my less file (which is in `http://localhost/css` folder):

```
@base: Site.base;

body{
  background: #71b7d6  url("@{base}/bg.jpg");   
}
```

Output when rendered with Less 1.3:

```
body{
  background: #71b7d6  url("http://localhost/css/http://localhost/images/bg.jpg");  
}
```

It was fine when I had Less 1.1.5.

Does anyone know what happened? I couldn't find it in their changelog.

It was actually an issue with less. https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/409

The solution stated in another post suggest set the variable to be a relative path with "/" in the front, however, this restricts the url to be in the same domain.

However, the error will popup somewhere else in the console when the browser try to resolve for simply `http://image/bg.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/409 was resolved a month ago. Update your LESS if you haven't already.